# Script for changing shortcut targets in a batch?

Tags: vbscript, virus

My external hard drive was recently affected by the recycler.exe virus when I lent it to a friend. The virus affects only external drives. It changes the folders into shortcuts to those folders via an EXE file that it creates.

I am searching for a script to change all the shortcut targets to **K:\{shortcut name}**. However, I don't know scripting and in the last two days that I have tried to learn scripting, I am not sure which one I should use. VBScript seems the best option, but that's just my opinion.

**Problem:**
For example, earlier I had a folder called 'Anime'. Now I have a shortcut linking to that folder with the following target:

*%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "start %cd%RECYCLER\894133bf.exe &&%windir%\explorer.exe %cd%Anime*

The virus also creates a folder(and file) **\RECYCLER\894133bf.exe** and the shortcuts are linked through that EXE file (seen above).

I would like a batch file to convert the target path to:
*K:\Anime*

This way the shortcut can directly link to the file. The virus and folder were removed by Norton when I got my hard drive back. However, the shortcuts remain and they don't work unless I change the target path.

Since I have over 37 folders on my hard drive which have been converted to the shortcuts, I was thinking that maybe a script would be helpful doing the following:

1. Extracting the filename from the shortcut
2. Removing the .lnk from filename
3. Changing the target to **K:\{shortcut name}**
4. Go to next folder and loop until last folder

I came across a script to extract a filename here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/05/30/how-can-i-extract-just-the-file-name-from-the-full-path-to-the-file.aspx

However, I do not know how to put it in a loop to do it for each folder.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

objFolder.Name in the For Loop is the string for each Folder it's iterating through.

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim strFolderToSearch, objFSO, objRootFolder, objFolder, colSubfolders, strOutput

    strFolderToSearch = InputBox("Enter Path:")

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objRootFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderToSearch)
    Set colSubfolders = objRootFolder.SubFolders

    For Each objFolder in colSubfolders
         strOutput = strOutput & objFolder.name
         strOutput = strOutput &  vbCrLf
         MsgBox StrOutput
    Next
```